# Electron js - dyld: Symbol not found: ___NSArray0__ Referenced from: /Users/martin/Desktop/electron-quick-s

Tags: javascript, macos, electron

I decided to try and learn electron so I cloned the
[electron quick start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) and installed the dependencies with `npm i` and ran `npm start` but I need help because of this error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: ___NSArray0__
  Referenced from: /Users/martin/Desktop/electron-quick-start/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/ReactiveObjC.framework/ReactiveObjC (which was built for Mac OS X 10.11)
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
 in /Users/martin/Desktop/electron-quick-start/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/ReactiveObjC.framework/ReactiveObjC
/Users/martin/Desktop/electron-quick-start/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron exited with signal SIGTRAP
```

Comment: Have you installed xcode? It might be issue with CoreFoundation.framework. Try to install xcode if you have not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron uses MacOS local frameworks, that weirdly enough, you don't seem to have on your computer.

Try to list your frameworks to confirm this: `ls -al /System/Library/Frameworks/`

If you don't have any, or [miss some of them](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SystemFrameworks/SystemFrameworks.html) (depending on your OS version), chances are you won't be able to build anything native at all, and your system should be all broken by now (plus, CoreFoundation is the *most important framework*): a clean install of the latest XCode won't install those frameworks back AFAIK.

Then, your options are:

- reinstall macOS
- get those framework from another mac using the same macOS version
- [grab them from your recovery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300222/accidentally-deleted-a-system-framework-macos-screwed)